# Node.js Discord.js Send message to channel from ID v11

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

In Discord.js V11 how can I send a message to a specific channel from the ID? (all I can find is on V12, I need V11) Thanks!

Comment: Is there any specific reason on why you don't want to update to v12? v13 is soon to fully release and Discord's addition of stage channels will break v11. The Discord.JS maintainers have been recommending to update for a while now. You **will** need to update sometime in the near future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/Client?scrollTo=channels) for v11, you can simply use `client.channels.get(id)` (without "fetch") to get the channel:

> All of the Channels that the client is currently handling, mapped by their IDs - as long as sharding isn't being used, this will be every channel in every guild, and all DM channels

You could then send a message to the channel:

```
const channel = client.channels.get('yourID');
channel.send('Hello!');
```